# Aptana 3 - Hangs with "Hooking file watcher to new project"

Tags: aptana, aptana3

After creating/importing any project in Aptana Studio 3, a task "Hooking file watcher to new project" appears and hangs. This prevents any other tasks happening on that project.

It's particularly annoying as all my work projects are stored in SVN and this prevents the initial checkout from taking place.

Edit: Just to add, this also prevents Aptana from quitting, forcing me to kill it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are no longer using our own implementation of watching for native file modifications to projects outside the IDE as of Studio 3.1, see https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-4302

So you can upgrade to 3.1, or you can explicitly turn off the filewatching in 3.0 by going into Preferences > Aptana Studio and unchecking the relevant option.

Comment: That would be great, if Aptana's update server were actually working...
I get: 

Unable to read repository at http://download.aptana.com/studio3-rcp/plugin/update/.
Permission denied